# SQL statement convert varchar to integer

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I was having some problem when trying to convert varchar field in MySQL to integer using SQL statement:

```
SELECT mrtpopTime, CONVERT(INT,mrtpopAmt)
FROM tm_mrtpop
WHERE mrtpopName = ''
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, mrtpopAmt) DESC
```

I am trying to get the top 3 records when mrtpopAmt was arranged in a way where it is in reverse order. However, I am getting error message at the INT and the error message is:

```
Syntax error, Unecpected INT_SYM
```

I wonder why is it so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because MySQL doesn't use `CONVERT()` for casting. It uses the [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function. In your case you would use:

```
CAST(mrtpopAmt AS SIGNED) -- This can also be UNSIGNED if it will always be a positive integer
```